# Fail while build pango-1.4.1

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, include, gtk, pango

Im trying to install pango-1.4.1 package to my Linux machine (a prerequisit to gtk+-2.0 lib). The used distro is:

```
CentOS release 5.9 (Final)
Linux 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5 #1 SMP Thu Feb 9 12:45:52 EST 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I dont have root authority on this machine Im just a simple user. I tried to install this package from tar.gz and with ./configure --prefix I define the desired destination folder (so I have write authority over that dir) and after the ./configure command I try to build pango with make, but I recieve the following errors and warnings:

```
ftxopen.c:23:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
ftxopen.c:24:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
ftxopen.c:25:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_LangSys':
ftxopen.c:44: warning: implicit declaration of function 'FT_FRAME_ENTER'
ftxopen.c:47: warning: implicit declaration of function 'FT_GET_USHORT'
ftxopen.c:51: warning: implicit declaration of function 'FT_FRAME_EXIT'
ftxopen.c:55: warning: implicit declaration of function 'FT_SET_ERROR'
ftxopen.c:55: warning: implicit declaration of function 'FT_MEM_ALLOC_ARRAY'
ftxopen.c:55: error: expected expression before 'FT_UShort'
ftxopen.c:60: warning: implicit declaration of function 'FT_FREE'
ftxopen.c:39: warning: unused variable 'memory'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_Script':
ftxopen.c:95: warning: implicit declaration of function 'FT_STREAM_POS'
ftxopen.c:107: warning: implicit declaration of function 'FT_STREAM_SEEK'
ftxopen.c:141: error: expected expression before 'TTO_LangSysRecord'
ftxopen.c:151: warning: implicit declaration of function 'FT_GET_ULONG'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_ScriptList':
ftxopen.c:225: error: expected expression before 'TTO_ScriptRecord'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_Feature':
ftxopen.c:322: error: expected expression before 'FT_UShort'
ftxopen.c:305: warning: unused variable 'memory'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_FeatureList':
ftxopen.c:374: error: expected expression before 'TTO_FeatureRecord'
ftxopen.c:376: error: expected expression before 'FT_UShort'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_Lookup':
ftxopen.c:611: error: expected expression before 'TTO_SubTable'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_LookupList':
ftxopen.c:709: error: expected expression before 'TTO_Lookup'
ftxopen.c:711: error: expected expression before 'FT_UShort'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_Coverage1':
ftxopen.c:798: error: expected expression before 'FT_UShort'
ftxopen.c:782: warning: unused variable 'memory'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_Coverage2':
ftxopen.c:847: error: expected expression before 'TTO_RangeRecord'
ftxopen.c:831: warning: unused variable 'memory'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_ClassDef1':
ftxopen.c:1086: error: expected expression before 'FT_UShort'
ftxopen.c:1059: warning: unused variable 'memory'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_ClassDef2':
ftxopen.c:1152: error: expected expression before 'TTO_ClassRangeRecord'
ftxopen.c:1131: warning: unused variable 'memory'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_ClassDefinition':
ftxopen.c:1206: error: expected expression before 'FT_Bool'
ftxopen.c:1203: warning: unused variable 'memory'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_EmptyClassDefinition':
ftxopen.c:1251: error: expected expression before 'FT_Bool'
ftxopen.c:1257: error: expected expression before 'FT_UShort'
ftxopen.c:1248: warning: unused variable 'memory'
ftxopen.c: In function 'Load_Device':
ftxopen.c:1433: error: expected expression before 'FT_UShort'
ftxopen.c:1408: warning: unused variable 'memory'
```

I think I dont have any dependencies left, here are the installed prerequisites with the version number:

```
glib-2.13.3
atk-1.0.3
freetype2-9.16.3 (aka freetype-2.5.3)
```

It would very important to be able to install pango. Can anyone help with it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there are improperly-formatted #includes in ftxopen.c at the listed lines. Fix those and probably most or all of the rest of the reported compile errors will go away.

Comment: There is a macro in after the #include directive which value is defined under freetype's internal.h file. This file is not installed it only exists under the installation folder of freetype. However i tried to include this header from there but I recieve the same message...

Comment: Okay. Are your dependencies installed using yum/rpm? If so, were  development files for the dependencies installed? Try 'yum search freetype-devel'. You may find the same to be true for other libraries pango depends on. You'll have to ask your sysadmin to install those.